# Substring permutation complexity

Tags: python, time-complexity, space-complexity

Just had a quick question about a Python implementation for the Leetcode question about substring permutations, as I'm a major newbie with algorithms:

> Given two strings s1 and s2, write a function to return true if s2 contains the permutation of s1. In other words, one of the first string's permutations is the substring of the second string.

Example 1:

```
Input: s1 = "ab" s2 = "eidbaooo"
Output: True
Explanation: s2 contains one permutation of s1 ("ba").
```

Example 2:

```
Input:s1= "ab" s2 = "eidboaoo"
Output: False
```

With one of the solutions given, I believe the following time complexity is O(n), but would the time complexity be O(1)? Additionally, would anyone have a resource for a Python implementation of a brute force approach? Thank you!

```
from collections import Counter

class Solution:
    def checkInclusion(self, s1: str, s2: str) -> bool:
        s1_count, s2_count = Counter(s1), Counter(s2[:len(s1)])
        
        for i in range(len(s2)-len(s1)):
            if s1_count == s2_count: 
                return True
            
            if s2_count[s2[i]] == 1: 
                del s2_count[s2[i]]
            else: 
                s2_count[s2[i]] -= 1
            
            if s2[i+len(s1)] in s2_count: 
                s2_count[s2[i+len(s1)]] += 1
            else: 
                s2_count[s2[i+len(s1)]] = 1
                
        return s1_count == s2_count
        
sol = Solution()
print(sol.checkInclusion('ab', 'eidbaooo'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time complexity of your own solution seems to be O(n) because the time is propotional to the length of input. O(1) means that the size of input doesn't matter which is not the case here. Creating and searching every possible permutations as in answer from inputvector is the brute force approach you are asking for and it is very slow when `len(s1)` is over 10. This has the very fast growing time complexity O(n!).

I couldn't help trying to beat your algorithm. Turns out I couldn't. Here is my attompt. It's a little faster on short strings up to around 6 characters in s1. It has O(n²) time compexity.

```py
def checkInclusion2(s1,s2):
    i = -1
    max_i = len(s2)-len(s1)+1
    while i < max_i:
        i += 1
        c = s2[i]
        if not c in s1:
            continue
        temp = list(s1)
        temp.remove(c)
        for j, c in enumerate(s2[i+1:i+len(s1)]):
            if c in temp:
                temp.remove(c)
            else:
                if c not in s1:
                    i += j
                break
        else:
            return True
    return False
```

So, then I tried to optimise yours and found out its faster to compare defaultdicts than Counters. And saving character from s2 in a temporary variable is faster than fetching it several times. This is twice as fast but that usually doesn't count in terms of time complexity. It's still O(n).

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def checkInclusion3(s1, s2):
    s1_count, s2_count = defaultdict(int), defaultdict(int)
    for i in range(len(s1)):
        s1_count[s1[i]] += 1
        s2_count[s2[i]] += 1
    for i in range(len(s2)-len(s1)):
        if s1_count == s2_count: 
            return True
        old_c = s2[i]
        if s2_count[old_c] == 1:
            del s2_count[old_c]
        else:
            s2_count[old_c] -= 1
        s2_count[s2[i+len(s1)]] += 1
    return s1_count == s2_count
```

Comment: Very nice! And apologies for still being majorly new to this area, but would the enumeration operation not bump the time complexity in your approach up to O(n), or would it be something else?

Comment: @ZapRowsdower You are right. Yours is faster. My take on it is bumped up to O(n*n).

Comment: @ZapRowsdower But i managed to optimise your solution :)

Comment: I had been doing a little browsing around over how a dict implementation might be shoehorned into this, so this approach is really neat. So that shakes out to O(2n) for the time complexity, and O(n) for space?

Comment: I'm not sure. I think my optimisation only manage to workaround quirks in python library and in terms of complexity don't differ from yours.  Actually since the function takes two argument the compexity also should have two arguments. With n = len(s1) and m = len(s2) the brute force is O(n!·m), yours and my optimisation is O(n+m) and my first attempt is something like O(n·m). When it comes to space I think the brute force needs O(n!+m) and the others maybe needs O(n)

Answer (score 1):

I think optimal solution is O(n) since you need to search all combination of s1 in s2. Here is a concise python solution:

```
from itertools import permutations

def find_subs(s1,s2):
    perms = [''.join(p) for p in permutations(s1)] # create all possible permutations of s1
    for p in perms: 
        if p in s2: #search it in s2
            return True
    return False

find_subs('ab',"eidbaooo")

True
```

Comment: Ooh, so just dump it into a comprehension. That would still shake out to a space complexity of O(1) though, correct?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Just what is provided in the example, so 'ab' and 'eidbaooo' for s1, s2 respectively. In which case, it might be closer to...O(n). I think...

Comment: You shouldn't think the complexity for one specific input. Btw, there is a problem in your examples both input are 'ab'

Comment: Thank you. And perhaps it was supposed to be "abb"? Here is a link to the problem, which was copied verbatim: https://leetcode.com/problems/permutation-in-string/